# Conditionals using two dates

Tags: r

Hello I have a database that has three columns, women, a date of birth of the child and a date of arrival in the country. The years data are in this format: "2020, 2021, etc". I need to create a new dataframe that contains only with women who arrived in the country at least two years before the birth of their children.

What conditional could I create?

```
Women        Date of Birth        Date of Arrival in the Country
Paula           2005                         2003
Andrea          2004                         2001
Drea            2001                         2000
```

Comment: `Date_of_Birth - Date_of_Arrival_in_the_Country >= 2`? `subset(your_data, Date_of_Birth - Date_of_Arrival_in_the_Country >= 2)`, as complete code?

Comment: Welcome to SO Rory! Note that Gregor replaced the spaces in the column names with underscores. This makes it easier to refer to columns.

Comment: Greetings! Instead of a table of your data, usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg